# How to change title "Search Results for:...." in search results page of genesis?

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

I want change title "Search Results for:...." in search results page because i want translate to Vietnamese. I use Genesis. Please help me!!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `'genesis_search_title_text'` filter:

```
add_filter( 'genesis_search_title_text', 'wpse_101947_search_title_text' );

function wpse_101947_search_title_text() {
    return 'Translated text';
}
```

Replace `Translated text` with your translated text.

Comment: Thank you very much! so, if i want redesign search results page, i want it only contains the title post, no contains post content. What should I do?

Comment: You should ask that as a new question. You might also include which child theme you are using. You shouldn't use Genesis directly as a theme.